# Android : Disabling a list item from the listview once selected

Tags: android, listview

I've a `ListView` with 10 items in the list.

Is it possible to disable the selected list item once clicked?
I'm using a custom Adapter. Help please? 
Thanks

EDIT :

`ListViewAdapter`:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;



HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView qs1;
    TextView qs2;


    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
    }




    resultp = data.get(position);


    qs2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qs);



    qs2.setText(resultp.get(Home.QUESTION));



    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            resultp = data.get(position);


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);


             intent.putExtra("question", resultp.get(Home.QUESTION));
             intent.putExtra("ques_id", resultp.get(Home.QUES_ID));



             context.startActivity(intent);


        }

    });
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by disable?  Do you want it to disappear or do you simply want it not to be clickable any more?  Also, please post the relevant parts of your custom Adapter.

Comment: Either option is fine. Posting the `Custom Adapter` now.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        arg0.setEnabled(false);

    }
});
```

this should disable the whole list view item.

Comment: Right. Can this be done inside `setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()` in my `adapter`?

Answer (score 0):

v.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
       if(arg2 == 0)
         {
           // 1st element out of 10, do nothing to disable this row

         }
      if(arg2 == 1)
         {
             // 2nd element out of 10, do nothing to disable this row
         }


    }
});
```